# Run tests in parallel with Guice and TestNg

Tags: java, testng, guice

Here's problem. I have some UI tests for one website. I use NavigationService to do some navigation on the page, such as open some page etc.

Here's **NavigationModule**

```
public class NavigationModule extends AbstractModule {

@Override
protected void configure() {
    bind(NavigationService.class).in(Singleton.class);
}
```

}

Here's **NavigationService**

```
public class NavigationService {

@Inject
private LoginPage loginPage;
@Inject
private TemplateManagementPage templateManagementPage;
@Inject
private CreateTemplatePage createTemplatePage;
@Inject
private NavigationMenu navigationMenu;

public TemplateManagementPage logIn(String username, String password) {
    return loginPage.login(username, password);
}

public TemplateManagementPage openTemplateManagementPage() {
    navigationMenu.openMenu()
    return templateManagementPage;
}}
```

And all above I use it in **BaseTest class** with @Guice annotation, here's code

```
@Guice(modules = NavigationModule.class)
public abstract class BaseTest extends BDDTest {

 protected String login = "login";
 protected String password = "pass";

 @Inject
 protected NavigationService navigationService;

 protected TemplateManagementPage templateManagementPage;

 @BeforeSuite
 public void login() {
     templateManagementPage = navigationService.logIn(login, password);
 }}
```

The last thing is I call this method in **@BeforeMethod**

```
public class TemplateWithLevelTest extends BaseTest {

private CreateTemplatePage templatePage;

@BeforeMethod(description = "Open create template page")
public void openCreateTemplatePage() {
    templatePage = navigationService.openCreateTemplatePage();
}

@Test()
public void someTest() {
    ...
}
```

Everything works fine, till I want run it in parallel from TestNg.xml, it opens one browser logging in and then opens another one with no page opened, then it throws

> Element not found {By.xpath: //div[@id='toast-container']}

NavigationModule is binded in Singleton, and as I get we should create different singletons for each thread, is there any way to do that?

Comment: There is no such a thing as "different singletons", A singleton is by definition a single instance shared by the whole application. You may need a thread-local, but I don't know this front-end technology you're using, so I'm afraid I can't help much..

Comment: Yeah, u right. The problem is that both threads using the same singleton, I know that we need thread-local, but I couldn't find any good example for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohhh, after few weeks, we finally did it. So [here's](https://github.com/codeborne/selenide/issues/629) the solution. Enjoy;)